Pylucene 8.11.0 installation on Ubuntu
I want to install pylucene 8.11.0 on ubuntu 64
I did python build and install
please help me to solve it
and when I want to make file I have this error
sudo make install
/usr/bin/python3 /usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/jcc/__init__.py
 --jar lucene-java-8.11.0/lucene/build/core/lucene-core-8.11.0.jar --jar 
lucene-java-8.11.0/lucene/build/analysis/common/lucene-analyzers-common-8.11.0.jar --jar
lucene-java-8.11.0/lucene/build/backward-codecs/lucene-backward-codecs-8.11.0.jar --jar
lucene-java-8.11.0/lucene/build/classification/lucene-classification-8.11.0.jar

I work with java 8_202 //this is my makefile updated
Linux     (Ubuntu 6.06, Python 2.4, Java 1.5, no setuptools)
//PREFIX_PYTHON=/usr
//ANT=ant
//PYTHON=$(PREFIX_PYTHON)/bin/python3
//JCC=$(PYTHON) $(PREFIX_PYTHON)/lib/python2.4/site-packages/jcc/__init__.py
//NUM_FILES=10

How I can solve Pylucene make error
